# Visual Studio 2008 Environment Variable Use at Compile Time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, environment-variables

I would like to compile in two environment variables (BUILD_NUMBER and NODE_NAME) that our Jenkins system defines so that these compile time values are saved, and then those saved values are accessed as our program is being run (regardless of what the user has presently set BUILD_NUMBER and NODE_NAME to.)

Is this possible using Visual Studio 2008? It would be nice if I could accomplish this entirely within our code, and did not have to modify the compilation system to pass anything along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way that you could make this work is by adding a pre-build step that executes a batch file with something like

```
>jenkins.h echo #define BUILD_NUMBER %BUILD_NUMBER%
```

Then from your source you `#include "jenkins.h"` and have immediate access to the macro `BUILD_NUMBER` which is baked in at compile time.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. If I do need to modify my build environment because Visual Studio will not support this, I think I will try this approach first.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the variables global and use `getenv` to retrieve them:

```
const char* buildNumber = getenv("BUILD_NUMBER");
const char* nodeName = getenv("NODE_NAME");
```

This isn't done at compile-time though, but if you only use the variables at run-time it shouldn't matter.

EDIT:

You could add `BUILD_NUMBER="$(BUILD_NUMBER)"` to your preprocessor directives in the project properties.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect, but I could be mistaken. Won't getenv() return a value at run time? I want the compile time value.

Comment: @BrianStinar yes. I provided another option.